# JSONP request to TinySong always failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp

I am trying to send a JSONP request to the tinysong api with the following code

```
var url = "http://tinysong.com/s/calvin+harris?format=json&limit=3&key=api_key"

function jsonpCallback(json) {
    console.log(json);
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url+'&callback=jsonpCallback';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

But keep on getting the message in the console

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

I also tried the following and got the same error

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});

function jsonCallback(json) { 
    console.log(json); 
}
```

I am sure the api is responding as I checked the network tab in chrome and can see a response from the API. Do you have any suggestions on what I can do, or I need to write a server side API which pings the TinySong api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding in your ajax call the item

```
    jsonp:true,
```

on the line before or after your jsonpCallback
also make sure your url has the '&callback=jsonpCallback' appended to it.

im looking at some old code of mine that works, and those are the only differences i see

Comment: So your suggestion somewhat worked, I can see that the response always goes to the error callback. Even though it is in the error callback I am now working on how to extract the data I need.

Comment: The problem appears to be that the TinySong API isn't JSONP-enabled. It sends back data as text/html instead of as javascript. Further, it ignores the callback parameter, thus never calling the success function on the client side.